# grouping data in single row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I create and populate the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE plch_sales
(
   product     VARCHAR2(10)
 , country     VARCHAR2(10)
 , year        NUMBER
 , sales       NUMBER
)
/

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('BANANA', 'US', 2009, 200);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('BANANA', 'US', 2010, 300);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('BANANA', 'GB', 2009, 400);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('BANANA', 'GB', 2010, 350);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('BANANA', 'DK', 2010, 250);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('APPLE' , 'US', 2009, 100);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('APPLE' , 'GB', 2009, 150);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('APPLE' , 'GB', 2010, 150);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('APPLE' , 'DK', 2009, 250);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('APPLE' , 'DK', 2010, 250);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('PEAR'  , 'GB', 2010, 150);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('PEAR'  , 'DK', 2009, 300);
   INSERT INTO plch_sales VALUES ('PEAR'  , 'DK', 2010, 350);

   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

My boss wants sales totals listed by product, by country and a grand total.

Which of the choices produce this desired output:

```
TOTAL   PRODUCT    COUNTRY         SALES
------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Product APPLE      TOTAL             900
Product BANANA     TOTAL            1500
Product PEAR       TOTAL             800
Country TOTAL      DK               1400
Country TOTAL      GB               1200
Country TOTAL      US                600
Grand   TOTAL      TOTAL            3200
```

I don't need only sql rather need to understand the technicality of sql. If any one could help please how to solve this type of sql queries?

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach that @GordonLinoff's answer to this is to split your problem into multiple queries that are easy to understand and union them:

```
select 'Product' as category, product as item, sum(sales) from plch_sales
group by product
union all
select 'Country' as category, country as item, sum(sales) from plch_sales
group by country
union all
select 'Total' as category, 'TOTAL' as item, sum(sales) from plch_sales
group by 1
```

yields

```
CATEGORY    ITEM    SUM(SALES)
Product     PEAR    800
Product     BANANA  1500
Product     APPLE   900
Country     US      600
Country     DK      1400
Country     GB      1200
Total       TOTAL   3200
```

A solution that yields the same result (with a little bit different columns), that's way easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks  @GordonLinoff and Chriz. I would have to understand how GROUPING function works also. Will follow somewhere to learn the implementation. The function seems to be so confusing , unable to get how it works.

Comment: @RajkumarMishra When using group by you tell oracle to take all records that are the same for the group condition (in this case `product`in the first query -> all records where product is BANANA, all records where product is PEAR etc.) and then select i.e. the max, min or something else among the other columns. in this case you select the sum of all sales where the column product is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grouping sets` and some conditional logic:

```
select (case when product is not null then 'Product'
             when country is not null then 'Country'
             else 'Total'
        end) as total,
       coalesce(product, 'Total') as product,
       coalesce(country, 'Total') as country,
       sum(sales)
from plch_sales
group by grouping sets ( (product), (country), () );
```

This uses the short-hand that `NULL` represents the grouping columns.  This works because you have no `NULL` values in this case.  You can also use the `GROUPING()` "function".